# Angular 9 consume REST API

Tags: angular, rest

i'm new to Angular and i'd like to use it for my front end.
i have a REST API in spring which gives the below Json content, 
My problem is that i manage to display the products  using a *ngFor,
 but i would like to display for each product his category.

I looked up on internet but it only explains how to show a simple entity, not the href links value.
thanks for your help

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "products" : [ {
      "id" : 4,
      "name" : "lKVOJRjKir",
      "description" : null,
      "currentPrice" : 405.0,
      "promotion" : true,
      "selected" : true,
      "available" : false,
      "photoName" : "unknown.jpeg",
      "quantity" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/4"
        },
        "product" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/4"
        },
        "category" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products/4/category"
        }
      }
```

this is my service:

```
 private getProducts(url) {
    this.catalogueService.getResource(url)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.products = data;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

this is my html file and what i've tried:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let p of products._embedded.products" >
     <div class="card" >
       <div class="card-header">{{p.name}}</div>
       <div>Price : {{p.currentPrice|number:'0.2'}}</div>
       <div>{{p.description}}</div>
       <div>Selected: {{p.selected}}</div>
       <div> Category: {{p.category.name}}</div>  // not working
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no category key in the above json object. If it is not returned for every product json object. You can go with safe operator in your html. 
{{p?.category?.name}}

Comment: yes i know the category is in the object but into a link with a href.I don't know how to access to its value and parameters....

Answer (score 0):

just to close the subject i found a solution which is to expose the category fields using :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpting-commonly-accessed-data